# Http Wire Level Logs in Netty

Tags: http, netty

Does any one knows on whether there is any inbuilt handlers from which we can see Http wire level logs. If I am a netty server, I might want to observe the inbound or outbound message in the wire. I am using Netty 4.x

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [LoggingHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/logging/LoggingHandler.java).

Add this object to your pipeline to enable logging:
`channel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));`

Comment: When your workplace creates their own wrappers that you can't (easily) modify this becomes a problem. I'm cursing the lack of dependency injection in my company's API.